# Passing knockout observables as parameters

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

Simple requirement - A knockout observable array in my view model which needs to be populated in a datacontext module. 2 different modules is the core of the problem.

The basic problem is that if a knockout observable is a function, how does one pass it as a parameter and what is the scope of such a variable. Is it global as it is an observable ?The pattern I am using is lifted straight from John Papa's SPA Jumpstart course but does not seem to work for me unless I have missed a bracket or a return statement somewhere. I have tried a number of different combinations.

Using JPs hot towel mvc template but that does not bear reference to my query .

Here is the view model code

```
define(['dataContext'], function (datacontext) {
    var summary = ko.observableArray();
    var initialise = false;

    var prodModel= {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Home View',
        summary:summary
    };

    return prodModel;



    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        if (!initialise)
        {

            initialise = true;
            return getSummary();


        }

        return;

    }
    function getSummary () {

   // Go to the context and populate the observable array
     return   datacontext.getProductionSummary(summary);

    };
    //#endregion
});
```

The following is the datacontext module. The error occurs when trying to assign the javascript array to the knockout observable array in the getProductionSummary method.

It is worth mentioning that I have attempted to use the pushAll utility function as well.

The only thing that populates the observable array is pushing into it directly but even if I do that I do not have the values in the calling viewmodel code as I would expect with an ordinary variable.

```
 define(['config','services/logger'],
function (config,logger) {


    var getProductionSummary = function (summaryObservableArray) {

     //Call Web API
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('getSummary');
        return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);

    //Yay got the data.. lets play
        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var summary = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                summary.push(data.results[i]);
            }


            return summaryObservableArray(summary);

        }


    };

    var datacontext = { getProductionSummary: getProductionSummary };
    return datacontext;



    // #region Internal functions  

    var manager = createBreezeManager();
    function createBreezeManager () {


        var mgr= new breeze.EntityManager(config.dataEndPoints);

        return mgr;
    };

    function queryFailed(error) {

        logger.log(error.message, null, 'dataContext', true);
    }
//#endregion





});
```

This is the bit in the view which throws the error

```
  <!--ko foreach:summary-->
                    <tr>

                        <td><span data-bind="text: summary().Count"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: summary().Percentage"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--/ko-->
```

The error is

```
Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError: summary is not defined;↵Bindings value: text: summary().Count
```

Comment: The scope of a KO observable variable (or property) is the same as that of *any* variable (or property). Also, don't forget to explain what "the error" is.

Comment: Yes, what is the error? But I will also say that returning `summaryObservableArray(summary)` is meaningless. That's because an observable simple does `return this;` when written, which in this case will be the `window` object.

Comment: this line `var manager = createBreezeManager();` is not executed and `manager.executeQuery(query)` should throw error.

Comment: Apologies..the error is Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError: summary is not defined;↵Bindings value: text: summary().Count

This is in the view model where I am databinding to summary().Count and summary().Percentage. Breeze is executing as it should. I can see the values being returned I can even see the value in my observablearray in the datacontext but then the binding fails.

Comment: I meant the error is in the view ...not the view model.

Answer (score 0):

@xdenser has correctly identified a most significant problem in your code.

```
return datacontext;
...
// never executed because you returned; manager is undefined.
var manager = createBreezeManager();
```

You didn't state the error. Our bet is that you get a "manager undefined" error when you call `getProductionSummary` in your viewmodel. Move the line up (preferably near the top of datacontext) and you'll be fine:

```
var manager = createBreezeManager();
...
return datacontext;
```

It all seems a bit tortured. Why not do away with `createBreezeManager` and just begin as follows?

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(config.dataEndPoints);
```

You also have a somewhat over-complicated `querySucceeded` which could be as simple as this:

```
function querySucceeded(data) { summaryObservableArray(data.results); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Ward. The breeze code executes fine. The value gets returned and the KO array in the datacontext gets populated but the binding on the view fails with the error summary is not defined.I have added the full error in an earlier comment.

The only reason that I am populating an array in the succeeded function is that I thought adding data.results directly into the observable is more expensive since there will be a notification fired with each item. Am I wrong ?

Comment: You are correct to pay attention to the danger of pushing items into an observable array. Fortunately, `data.results` **is an array already**. By using it directly you do the same thing as when you constructed `summary` and injected that.

Answer (score 0):

data-bind="text: summary().Count == WRONG 
 data-bind="text: Count== RIGHT

Duh.. Got thrown by the error statement. But thanks all for responding.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--ko foreach:summary-->
         <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Count"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Percentage"></span></td>
         </tr>
<!--/ko-->
```

this is correct view

inside `foreach` binding context is array item. 
still do not understand how your dataContext module works. suspect you are showing not actual code.